# Amcharts dataloader multiple datasets

Tags: json, amcharts

Can someone please explain how I can use multiple CSV/JSON files with amCharts and the Data Loaderfunction?

My code is:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
        type: "stock",
        datasets:[{
            title: "Outdoor",
            fieldmappings: [{
                fromField: "timestamp",tofield: "timestamp"
            },{
                fromField: "temp", tofield: "temp"
            },{
                fromField: "id", tofield: "id"
            }],
            compared: false,
            categoryField: "timestamp",
            dataLoader: {
                url: "/sensor-data.php?action=csv_data&id=AB&period=48",
                showCurtain: true,
                async: true,
                reverse: true,
                useColumnNames: true, 
                showErrors: true,
            complete: function ( chart ) {
                console.log( "Loading complete" );
            },
            load: function ( options, chart ) {
                console.log( "File loaded: ", options.url );
            },
            error: function ( options, chart ) {
                console.log( "Error occured loading file: ", options.url );
            }
            }}],    
        pathToImages: "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/images/",

        //Python: 2015-10-27 08:43:00 YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss */
        //PHP: 2015-10-27 09:24:06 YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss */
        dataDateFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS",
        startDuration: 1,
        categoryAxis: {
            parseDates: true,
            minPeriod : "10mm",
            gridPosition: "start"
        },
        valueAxes: [ {
                    id: "v1",
                    gridAlpha: 0.07
        }],
        graphs: [ {
            type:"line",
            valueAxis: "v1",
            title: "AB",
            valueField: "temp",
            lineThickness: 2
            }
        ],
         "legend": {}
    } );
```

I can't work out how I can display another dataset where the url would be: `"/sensor-data.php?action=csv_data&id='AB'&period=24"`

**EDITTED/UPDATED:** In line with @martynasma comments below, I've updated the code but I get nothing displayed and the data for the graph doesn't load.

Comment: You need to make clearer what you want to achieve. Do you want to load several data sets to feed several graphs? Or do you want to load another data set after some user interaction dynamically?

Comment: The two datasets are from a PHP script and have the urls: `/sensor-data.php?action=csv_data&id='AA'&period=24"` and `/sensor-data.php?action=csv_data&id='AB'&period=24"`.  I'm looking for an example or guidnance on how I load these two datasets on the same graph.

Comment: Further to this it seems when I use `dataSets: [{ dataLoader: { url: "/.....` I don't get a graph drawn.

Comment: Data sets are feature of Stock Chart, not regular serial chart. So you will need to use Stock Chart for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple 'dataLoader'

```
  ....
    dataLoader: {
     url:'...',

   },
   dataLoader: {
     url:'...',

   }
   .....
```

and son on